# Colour links of a d3 network graph according to a data variable

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I would like to colour different links of a network graph according to a value within a data vector (where each element of the vector corresponds to a particular link). I have tried something of the form:

```
var data = [1,1,1,2];

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
.data(force.links())
.enter()
.append("line")
.attr("class", "link")
.attr("marker-end", "url(#end)")
.on("mouseover", linkmouseover)
.on("mouseout", linkmouseout);
link.data(force.links()).enter().append(".link")
.style("stroke", function(d,i){
return ( (data[i]==2) ?
         "red" : "black" )
});
```

However, this does not seem to work. If it's important I also have an svg styling:

```
 .link {
stroke: #ff0000;
opacity: 0.6;
stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working? I have the Plunker version [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Rmc0XaDonCiIDfzMdlm5?p=preview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are setting up your links looks quite odd. Especially the following line doesn't seem to make any sense:

```
link.data(force.links()).enter().append(".link")
```

The statement directly preceding this line successfully inserts the lines for the links handling the enter selection. On the suspicious line you are then binding the same data *again* to the links' selection. Because you did not specify any key function to access your data this will compute a join based on the data's index which will, because you handled this same data before, yield an empty enter selection. Therefore, the method setting `style("stroke",...)` will never execute the callback. Furthermore, the call to `.append(".link")` is wrong, because `.link` is not a valid SVG element which could be appended using this method.

You somehow seem to have messed up this part of your code by, maybe, some copy&paste action. If you get rid of the above mentioned line and delete the directly preceding semicolon your code will work as expected:

```
var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
  .data(force.links())
    .enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)")
  .on("mouseover", linkmouseover)
  .on("mouseout", linkmouseout)
  .style("stroke", function(d,i){
    return ( (data[i]==2) ? "red" : "black" );
  });
```

Have a look at the [updated code](http://plnkr.co/edit/lhidlAQ0FWtohvodqAGL?p=preview) for a working example.